# Unable to select my custom login page from experience builder page at community's login& registration setting

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, customer-community, login

I need my custom login page for community because standard login page can not freely customize. I created custom login page with aura component and embedded to my custom login page called as AnyTest Login. I want to set my custom login page to my community's default login page, therefore I tried at the community administration setting's login page type.

Searched my custom login page via keyword but it wasn't shown at "Experience Builder Page". Only was shown "main" and "login".
Is this bug? How do I set my custom login page as default login page?

1. My Custom Login Page & embedded aura component
   [image]
2. Set my custom login page to community's default login page
   [image]
3. Added new page variation in Login Page.
   [image]
4. I want this layout.
   [image]
5. But my custom content layout and component was **auto resized** in the new page variation(AnyTestLogin) of login page.
   [image]

Comment: Not sure if this would still help anyone but I found that the custom login page requires the /s/ part of the URL. So the login page should be accessed through <hostURL>/<communityname>/s/login.

Answer (score 0):

The login page is a special template page and only that can be used as the login page.

Now looking at your previous question it seems like you are not able to modify the layout. You should be able to modify the layout easily from the layout section.

[image: Layout]

If not then you can create a new variation and mark it as default.

[image: Variation]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Added new page variation but my custom content layout and component was auto resized, That's why, I told "can not freely customize in Login page". Pls refer to the question's image(from No.3 to 5)

Comment: In that case you will have to modify the community CSS from and add a min width property for each device size. Just for testing, you can add div{min-width:900px !important} or you can put your component in a VF page so you have control over the layout.

Comment: you will have to modify the community CSS from and add a min width property for each device size -> OK, I See. you can put your component in a VF page -> It's means, I have to wrap my aura component to VF page and need to use login page type is visualforce?